# error with maindata in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I have this problem (Type any has no subscript members) in this line `

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,GADBannerViewDelegate {    

    @IBOutlet weak var BannerView: GADBannerView!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBAction func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        get()
    }

    var values:NSArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
        BannerView.delegate = self
        BannerView.adUnitID = ""
        BannerView.rootViewController = self
        BannerView.load(request)

        get();
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func get(){
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.X.php")
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray

        tableView.reloadData()            
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return values.count;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SpecialCell

        let maindata = values[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        cell.info!.text = maindata ["Info"] as String?

        return cell;
    }
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1W0m.png)

thank you all..

Comment: Please take some time to nicely format your question. Use the `{ }` button to format the code. Remove multiple blank lines. Specify on which line the error occurs.

Comment: The reason of your issue is the usage of `NSArray`. It lacks any type information. Further – but not related – `.mutableContainers` is completely meaningless in Swift and loading data synchronously from a remote URL is very bad programming habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to give mainData a type like this:

`let maindata = values[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as? [String:Any]`

and then make sure mainData actually contains a value

```
if let info = mainData?["Info"] as? String {
    cell.info!.text = info
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all declare the data source array as Swift `Array`. Foundation `NSArray` has no type information and doesn't help Swift's strong type system at all.

```
var values = [[String:Any]]()
```

Then load the data asynchronously(!) and reload the table view on the main thread

```
func get() {
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.X.php")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
           print(error!)
        } else {
           do {
              self.values = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.tableView.reloadData() 
              }
           } catch {
              print(error)
           }
        }           
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Then in `cellForRow` assign the value

```
let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
cell.info!.text = maindata["Info"] as? String
```

Now the compiler knows all subscripted types and the error goes away.